# Cant Access BIOS

Tags: bios, uefi

I am unable to access Bios on my system. I disabled Fast startup and my Bios mode is UEFI. I need to enable Virtulization for Docker. I have tried advanced startup but still unable to access UEFI Firmare options.
I have a lenovo z570 and swapped the HDD to SSD. even If I press the buttons F2 (for setup) and F12 ( for Multiboot - which has an option to adjust by opening BIOS) but nothings working.
I really appriciate your Help.

Comment: Since you swapped HDD to SSD can you even remove the SSD and just try to boot it without OS and see if it can now enter BIOS/UEFI? Alternatively if the battery is removable (easily accessible for removal) try to remove the battery and re-insert. If battery is not removable check if the laptop is equipped with a pinhole to simulate battery removal.

Comment: Another thing to try is to start the system and allow to be fully started. Now do a Restart.  This introduces a delay and may allow you to get into BIOS. There may be a message on the loading screen about how to do this.

Comment: @patkim. I am using the laptop without battery, I have tried pulling the plug out multiple times and then starting it . Didn't work.

Comment: Tried that as well @John. Any other way to boot to bios?

Comment: Even if I am not able to boot to bios. If I am able to enable virtualization I am good.

Comment: And what if you boot without any disk (HDD/SSD)? Were you able to access BIOS before or is this the first time you tried?

Comment: Try looking in MSCONFIG  (WinKey + R and enter MSCONFIG)  See if any of the options help you (may no GUI boot). I don't think so, but try.

Comment: Thanks @John, Tried that didnt work. I am thinking of downloading a Virtualbox and then installing the docker.